# What bottom bracket type is this?

Tags: bottom-bracket

Can you help me identify the bottom bracket for the following please.

The frame is a Norco One25 (version 3)

It does not appear to have internal threads.

The diameter is approx 6.3cm and the length is approx 7cm

It is an old dirt jump bike style frame - maybe from 2003.

I found a picture of the frame here, https://webimg.secondhandapp.com/w-i-mgl/5af860e8d31b2f5a14ce2cca

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Spec says "Sealed 19mm Mid BB", which is a BMX style.  Bearings press in.

Comment: thanks - where did you find the spec ?

Comment: DuckDuckGo gave me this as the first result searching for the brand and model you provided in the question: https://www.norco.com/bike-archives/2018/one25/ There's a small parts spec sheet linked there

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the question, with a picture of the frame, I think its from 2003

Comment: I found specs for a 2004 which used a  KUE Q Z-2000 bottom bracket and crankset. There are lots of threads looking for these obsolete parts, the links to replacements also seem obsolete, Do you have the crank ? That is an important factor as to what will fit.

Comment: no I only have frame, form and wheels - it was an impulse buy from the bay!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be American. Corroborate 51mm bore. If so that's what it is. It wants a BMX three piece and matching BB, depending on your crank choice. Mid didn't exist in 03, or at least that was a few years before its mainstream emergence.

Comment: Thanks, are we saying its one similar to this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Savage-Bicycle-Cycle-Bike-American-BMX-Mid-BB-Set-Sealed-Bearing-Black-19-MM-/274162358610 the size looks about the same.

Comment: @garyconstable No, that is a Mid that someone put "American" in the title for no reason. If this is confusing find the BB comparison page on any of the BMX online sellers, ie Dan's Comp or Albe's. You need to measure the bore and confirm it's 51mm. Also confirm that your 63 is an OD measure of the shell. Shell OD is meaningless re standard/type because the wall thickness is arbitrary and has more to do to with the material choice etc.

Comment: Yes this correct - 51 inside and 63mm outside

Comment: @garyconstable Yes, so American.

Comment: I see, something like this - https://www.danscomp.com/profile-racing-american-bottom-bracket-kit-gold-19mm-bbam6819gld/p1132635?v=1072387

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you want to run something other than a BMX crank you can adapt it, but I wouldn't bother. You mostly just need to choose a crank and buy a BB and sprocket that match its spindle diameter (sprockets usually can adapt to either 22 or 19.) If you're building it up with an RD you can think about getting a NW ring, which didn't exist at the time but would make sense now probably.

Comment: Thanks for all the info - I was thinking about a single speed - not sure if it matters, I have a rear wheel with a 9 speed shimano style hub attached, it currently has a nine speed deore cassette  -  do i need a new hub for a single gear ?

Comment: No, you would just use that wheel with a single speed cog and a spacer/lockring kit. You'll need to make sure you understand how to choose the gearing you want. Since you're working from scratch you get to choose how small you want the drivetrain.